# This view works in PouchDB but why does it fail to sync with CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

After some time developing an app with PouchDB I am now beginning my first attempts at syncing with a remote CouchDB instance. For now I am only syncing with the CouchDB provided by the installable OSX CouchDB app.

Documents appear to sync fine but I am having trouble with a particular view. I've checked it is valid JS and can't see an error.

I am storing each view in its own design document, which I read is a best practise.

**So far I've tried:**

- Removing `toLowerCase()` (no reason really, just to check)
- Moving the value emitted into its own variable

Other folk have had issues with view sync due to the use of modern JS features but I believe I've written mine with ES5, which I've read is what is required.

**Here is the view definition code:**

```
const ddoc = {
  _id: '_design/title-only',
  views: {
    'title-only': {
      map: function titleOnly(doc) {
        if (doc.type && doc.type === 'song' && doc.title) {
          emit(doc.title.toLowerCase(), {
            id: doc._id,
            title: doc.title,
            authors: doc.authors,
            starred: doc.starred || false,
            labels: doc.labels || [],
            createdAt: doc.createdAt,
          });
        }
      }.toString(),
    },
  }
};
```

I get an error of type "compilation_error".

**Here is the error message:**

```
"Compilation of the map function in the 'title-only' view failed: Expression does not eval to a function. (function titleOnly(doc) {
                                if (doc.type && doc.type === 'song' && doc.title) {
                                    emit(doc.title.toLowerCase(), {
                                        id: doc._id,
                                        title: doc.title,
                                        authors: doc.authors,
                                        starred: doc.starred || false,
                                        labels: doc.labels || [],
                                        createdAt: doc.createdAt,
                                    });
                                }
                            })"
```

Any pointers gratefully received, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a named function.

In other words, replace this:

```
map: function titleOnly(doc) {
```

with this:

```
map: function(doc) {
```